# How to disable quantity edit in frontend for grouped products

Tags: magento-1, simple-product, grouped-products, quantity

**Some Brief**

I want to sell products like tea, coffee, juice etc they are in small packets each packet cost is around $3.73. For this i will make it `simple product` in magento. So when customer will purchase it. Its quantity will be deducted.

**BUT**

I also have 3 subscription plans, before becoming our customer he/she will `compulsory` have to buy `subscription plan first`, and it is `one time only`, then later customer can purchase individual products according to his needs in terms of quantity. But on first transaction they have to buy subscription plan only. Now, in that subscription plans i am selling the same `simple products` in multiple quantity that means `in first plan coffee 20 packates` and `in second plan coffee 30 packages` and so on.

**Now, lets come to problem according to magento's flow.**

If i enter all the product as `simple products` in magento admin, this will be okay for individual packets selling, but how will i manage them in subscription plans because when someone will purchase subscription plans we have to deduct 20 quantity from the same `simple product`

**What i did**

I have tried adding it as grouped product and i think it will serve my purpose, but in groped products also in `Associated Products` section there is column of putting quantity that is perfect for me. But that `quantity is editable in frontend`. Is there any possibility to disable it so that `customer will buy the quantity what i want him to buy` he should not be able to edit that quantity.

**Any help would be greatly appreciated.**

Answer (score 0):

I digged into this and found the solution, so I've decided to post it as an answer.

The answer to this question is `BUNDLED PRODUCT TYPE` bundled product has the options to disable user input and it displays the default selected options from admin, this solves the purpose of not allowing user to edit quantity in fronend and manage it backend at the same time.

Please refer below screenshot
[image]

Hope it helps someone else.

Comment: Well, except that you now have a bundled product which is displayed as 1 product on your invoice, whereas a grouped is just a way of adding several products in the cart at the same time.

Comment: I was looking for the same thing but really needed each product invoiced separately, I went to `/template/catalog/product/view/type/grouped.phtml` and added `readonly` at the end of `<input>` in the qty section