# Grouped products associate quantity cart magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a Magento 1.9 installation. and in it I have grouped virtual simple products and it works very well. In the grouping I have two products, and I would like that in the shopping cart when choosing the grouped product the first and second product of the group have the same amount.
For example, if I have the quantity of 2 products in the first one, the second one is the same (2). and that the second one cannot be changed.

Thanks

D.Witoszek Arias

Comment: You need to make custom extension for this one.

Comment: The solution for me was https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105926/how-to-disable-quantity-edit-in-frontend-for-grouped-products